# Search Field in Django Python

Tags: python, django

First, I have to say that is this my first application in Django. So my knowledge is still limited.

I have this home page where it shows all the data in my model. The model name is "Asset".

I am trying to have a search field inside the home page.

models.py

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    asset_desc = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False)
    BEIRUT = 'Beirut'
    SAIDA = 'Saida'
    HALBA = "Halba"
    base_choice = ((SAIDA, "Saida"), (BEIRUT, "Beirut"), (HALBA, "Halba"))
    asset_base = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False, choices=base_choice)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    asset_user = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.asset_desc)
        super(Asset, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.asset_desc
```

views.py

```
def search_asset(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
    assets = Asset.objects.filter(asset_desc__icontains=q)
    context = {'desc': assets}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

html for the search field:

```
    <form method="GET" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."id="search_box" name="q">
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', "asset.views.search_asset", name="home")
```

Please any help on why it is not showing the result. I am using Django 1.9.

Comment: What is your template for showing the results? What is passed as `q` for testing?

Comment: so what is the issue ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: There's nothing obvious by looking at your code. You need to do some work in order to show us some more details. 1. Check in your views.py by printing or using `pdb` to find out if `q` actually has value. 2. Use the same method to find out if `assets` is empty. 3. You need to update your question to show your code for how do you render the result.

Comment: code looks fine, what happens when you submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some corrections:

you dont need `null=False` for TextField() and CharField(), since they never save Null to database but empty string. so you can remove `null=False`

the search url name is `home` which logically not really approriate. it should be changed to `search` or `search_view` and then you can refer to it via `url` tag:

```
action="{% url 'search' %}"
```

this is useful if someone should look over your code. "Readability counts" ;)

and finally, put this to your home.html (actually you must already have it)

```
{% for asset in desc %}
    <div>
        {{ asset.asset_desc }} <br>
        {{ asset.base_choice }} <br>
        {{ asset.asset_user }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope, this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I was missing is the action and the url correction you provided. It worked now.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the template or the HTML portion where you list the results. You should consider the name of you context variable, but by following your name, you should list the results like this:

```
{% for asset in desc %}
    <div>
    {{ asset }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Anything else looks correct.

Hope it helps